# How to ask to send a busd transaction using ethers

Tags: ether, bsc

I have tried to make a function in a dapp to ask the user to send X BUSD to a wallet. The problem is that I cannot  figure out how to make it ask for BUSD instead of ETH.

```
    try {
        if (!window.ethereum)
            throw new Error('No ethereum provider found');
        await window.ethereum.request({method: "eth_requestAccounts"});
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
        const signer = await provider.getSigner();
        ethers.utils.getAddress(address);
        const tx = await signer.sendTransaction({
            to: address,
            value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1"),
        });
        console.log(tx);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
```

This is the code that I have, but I would like to send BUSD, instead of ETH.

Answer (score 0):

Token transfers work very differently.

To transfer X amount of token Y, you have to call the Y's token contract's transfer functionality. So you issue the transaction to the token contract, not to the receiver of the tokens. The transaction data then dictates who is the receiver of the tokens, and how many.

You should research token transfers more, there are plenty of tutorials available online.